# How to uncheck a checkbox by checking whether it is already clicked or not in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, checkbox, webdriverwait

Clicked a checkbox and how to deselect that checkbox

```
domestic=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="chkGraphic_0"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",domestic)
```

Comment: No have to check whether it is selected or not and then it has to be clicked @Guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want check first the checkbox have checked or not, use `.is_selected()`:

```
domestic=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="chkGraphic_0"]')
if domestic.is_selected():
    #uncheck
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",domestic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `execute_script()` isn't an ideal way to **click** a *checkbox* for selecting/deselecting it. The relevant [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) would have helped us to construct a canonical answer. However, to select/deselect a *checkbox* you need to to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#chkGraphic_0"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='chkGraphic_0']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: @MonikRaj Update the question with the relevant HTML and the complete error stacktrace.

Comment: Its working by using try and expect @DebanjanB But I want to  unclick the box by checking whether it is already clicked or not

Comment: @MonikRaj That would need a oneline logic. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement?

Comment: Sometimes websites these days are built weirdly and a click on the checkbox is just not doing what it's suppose to - It might help clicking the <label> instead.